# How to send a axios http put request only if there is a change on the object in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, vuejs2, axios

What is the logical way to send an *axios http put* request only if there is a **change** on the object and its properties?

I'm finding that I am firing unnecessary http requests which is a waste on the server power.  I would like to limit to only firing if the object I am sending has been updated or changed from the original version when the page loaded.

My main reason for this is that I am using automatic saving on input via @blur and therefore there is a lot of action happening on the http front!

`<input @blur="editInput()"></input>`

The method `editInput()` fires axios put http request every time.  Needs a method to check for change?

Do you clone the object on the `created()` hook perhaps?  And then use some method to compare... was what I attempted but failed.

Comment: try using a watch property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    foo: {
      bar: {
        baz: 'foo bar baz'
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    message(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue != oldValue) alert('change 1')
    },
    'foo.bar.baz'(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue != oldValue) alert('change 2')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>

  <input v-model="message">
  <input v-model="foo.bar.baz">

</div>
```

Comment: Ah Of course!  Thanks.  How to watch the nested properties though with this approach?

Comment: Awesome, cheers!  Is it possible to watch just `foo` from a top level without declaring each property individually?

Comment: @Jquestions as @BoussadjraBrahim mentioned, you can use a [`deep watcher`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

Answer (score 1):

You could watch deeply your property as follows :

```
watch: {
    person: {
        handler: (newValue,oldValue) {

        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```